# Integrating Google and Apple Wallet Passes in React App

Tags: apple-wallet, google-wallet

I'm looking for guidance on implementing `Google` and `Apple Wallet` Passes in a `React` app. Specifically, I need to understand how to use the `Google Wallet API` and `Apple Wallet API` to create passes from our app.

The goal is to generate a pass that can be sent to users via email and easily added to their phone wallet.

Could someone provide a step-by-step walkthrough or point me to relevant documentation and examples?

Comment: Check out passninja.com 